# How can I use the variable "qemu_name" defined in softmmu/globals.c in QEMU in hw/core/irq.c?

Tags: c, makefile, arm, qemu, meson-build

I want to use "qemu_name" variable in hw/core/irq.c. I added `#include "sysemu/sysemu.h"` in hw/core/irq.c, because "qemu_name" declared as an extern variable in sysemu/sysemu.h.(`extern const char *qemu_name;`)

I want to use "qemu_name" in hw/core/irq.c as below;

```
#include "qemu/osdep.h"
#include "qemu/main-loop.h"
#include "hw/irq.h"
#include "qom/object.h"

#include "sysemu/sysemu.h"

void qemu_set_irq(qemu_irq irq, int level)
{
  if (!irq)
      return;

  //SOME CODE HERE
  
  if (qemu_name != NULL) {
  
  //SOME CODE HERE
  
  }
}
```

When I try to compile QEMU I got error like below;

```
 make -j 4
  GIT     ui/keycodemapdb tests/fp/berkeley-testfloat-3 tests/fp/berkeley-softfloat-3 dtc slirp
[1/20] Generating qemu-version.h with a custom command (wrapped by meson to capture output)
[2/5] Compiling C object libhwcore.fa.p/hw_core_irq.c.o
[3/5] Linking static target libhwcore.fa
[4/5] Linking target tests/unit/test-qdev-global-props
FAILED: tests/unit/test-qdev-global-props
cc -m64 -mcx16  -o tests/unit/test-qdev-global-props tests/unit/test-qdev-global-props.p/test-qdev-global-props.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -pie -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--start-group libevent-loop-base.a libqom.fa libhwcore.fa -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong libqemuutil.a subprojects/libvhost-user/libvhost-user-glib.a subprojects/libvhost-user/libvhost-user.a libqom.fa libhwcore.fa /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -Wl,--end-group
/usr/bin/ld: libhwcore.fa.p/hw_core_irq.c.o: warning: relocation against `qemu_name' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: libhwcore.fa.p/hw_core_irq.c.o: in function `qemu_set_irq':
/qemu-7.1.0/cmake/build_aarch64/../../hw/core/irq.c:68: undefined reference to `qemu_name'
```

**EDIT-1:**
I think the error is caused by the compilation sequence, because globals.c needs to be compiled first and then irq.c. Otherwise qemu-name will be unusable in irq.c. So how can I configure the compilation order?

**EDIT-2:**
QEMU repository link for those who don't know:
https://github.com/qemu/qemu/tree/v7.1.0